# LINQPad DirectoryNotFoundException: "Could not find a part of the path"

Tags: configuration, module

With Sitecore 8.0 update 5 and LINQPad Sitecore Driver 1.9.0.2 I am receiving the following error when attempting to run a vanilla query:

[image: LINQPad Screenshot]

It's strange that this isn't utilizing the specified web root as a base.

A couple other people have reported this issue as well without a resolution:

1. https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/getting_to_know_sitecore/posts/linqpad-driver-for-sitecore-1-9
2. https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/getting_to_know_sitecore/posts/linqpad-driver-for-sitecore-1-9-0-2

Is this a bug in the driver? There isn't a reported issue in the [github repo](https://github.com/adamconn/sitecore-linqpad/issues)

Has anyone else encountered this issue as well and has been able to identify a solution? This doesn't seem to be folder permission related.